# How to get element by Index in Spark RDD (Java)

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I know the method rdd.firstwfirst() which gives me the first element in an RDD.

Also there is the method rdd.take(num) Which gives me the first "num" elements.

But isn't there a possibility to get an element by index?

Thanks.e

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This should be possible by first indexing the RDD. The transformation `zipWithIndex` provides a stable indexing, numbering each element in its original order.

Given: `rdd = (a,b,c)`

```
val withIndex = rdd.zipWithIndex // ((a,0),(b,1),(c,2))
```

To lookup an element by index, this form is not useful. First we need to use the index as key:

```
val indexKey = withIndex.map{case (k,v) => (v,k)}  //((0,a),(1,b),(2,c))
```

Now, it's possible to use the `lookup` action in PairRDD to find an element by key:

```
val b = indexKey.lookup(1) // Array(b)
```

If you're expecting to use `lookup` often on the same RDD, I'd recommend to cache the `indexKey` RDD to improve performance.

How to do this using the [Java API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html) is an exercise left for the reader.

Comment: Also remember that the RDD's ordering is undefined unless it's sorted. It can change every time it's evaluated otherwise. You can also `map(_.swap)` to switch keys and values.

Comment: What you left "as an exercise for the reader" is the main complexity in this question.

Comment: @user1843507 What would you consider missing? `zipWithIndex` and  `lookup` are the same in Java, so only the `map` function requires some small effort to swap the values of the (key, value) into (value, key) that's not core for this question.

Comment: Old thread, but I've added a Java based answer (albeit looking for a range of records not an individual record).

Comment: You really want `indexKey` to be partitioned.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this class to fetch an item by index. First, when you construct `new IndexedFetcher(rdd, itemClass)`, it counts the number of elements in each partition of the RDD. Then, when you call `indexedFetcher.get(n)`, it runs a job on only the partition that contains that index.

Note that I needed to compile this using Java 1.7 instead of 1.8; as of Spark 1.1.0, the bundled org.objectweb.asm within com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm cannot read Java 1.8 classes yet (throws IllegalStateException when you try to runJob a Java 1.8 function).

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.TaskContext;
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD;

import scala.reflect.ClassTag;

public static class IndexedFetcher<E> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public final RDD<E> rdd;
    public Integer[] elementsPerPartitions;
    private Class<?> clazz;
    public IndexedFetcher(RDD<E> rdd, Class<?> clazz){
        this.rdd = rdd;
        this.clazz = clazz;
        SparkContext context = this.rdd.context();
        ClassTag<Integer> intClassTag = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.<Integer>apply(Integer.class);
        elementsPerPartitions = (Integer[]) context.<E, Integer>runJob(rdd, IndexedFetcher.<E>countFunction(), intClassTag);
    }
    public static class IteratorCountFunction<E> extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction2<TaskContext, scala.collection.Iterator<E>, Integer> implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override public Integer apply(TaskContext taskContext, scala.collection.Iterator<E> iterator) {
            int count = 0;
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                count++;
                iterator.next();
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
    static <E> scala.Function2<TaskContext, scala.collection.Iterator<E>, Integer> countFunction() {
        scala.Function2<TaskContext, scala.collection.Iterator<E>, Integer> function = new IteratorCountFunction<E>();
        return function;
    }
    public E get(long index) {
        long remaining = index;
        long totalCount = 0;
        for (int partition = 0; partition < elementsPerPartitions.length; partition++) {
            if (remaining < elementsPerPartitions[partition]) {
                return getWithinPartition(partition, remaining);
            }
            remaining -= elementsPerPartitions[partition];
            totalCount += elementsPerPartitions[partition];
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Get %d within RDD that has only %d elements", index, totalCount));
    }
    public static class FetchWithinPartitionFunction<E> extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction2<TaskContext, scala.collection.Iterator<E>, E> implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private final long indexWithinPartition;
        public FetchWithinPartitionFunction(long indexWithinPartition) {
            this.indexWithinPartition = indexWithinPartition;
        }
        @Override public E apply(TaskContext taskContext, scala.collection.Iterator<E> iterator) {
            int count = 0;
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                E element = iterator.next();
                if (count == indexWithinPartition)
                    return element;
                count++;
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Fetch %d within partition that has only %d elements", indexWithinPartition, count));
        }
    }
    public E getWithinPartition(int partition, long indexWithinPartition) {
        System.out.format("getWithinPartition(%d, %d)%n", partition, indexWithinPartition);
        SparkContext context = rdd.context();
        scala.Function2<TaskContext, scala.collection.Iterator<E>, E> function = new FetchWithinPartitionFunction<E>(indexWithinPartition);
        scala.collection.Seq<Object> partitions = new scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.ofInt(new int[] {partition});
        ClassTag<E> classTag = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.<E>apply(this.clazz);
        E[] result = (E[]) context.<E, E>runJob(rdd, function, partitions, true, classTag);
        return result[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got stuck on this for a while as well, so to expand on Maasg's answer but answering to look for a range of values by index for Java (you'll need to define the 4 variables at the top):

```
DataFrame df;
SQLContext sqlContext;
Long start;
Long end;

JavaPairRDD<Row, Long> indexedRDD = df.toJavaRDD().zipWithIndex();
JavaRDD filteredRDD = indexedRDD.filter((Tuple2<Row,Long> v1) -> v1._2 >= start && v1._2 < end);
DataFrame filteredDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(filteredRDD, df.schema());
```

Remember that when you run this code your cluster will need to have Java 8 (as a lambda expression is in use).

Also, zipWithIndex is probably expensive!

Comment: hi, can you please guide similar solution for Java 7 ?

Comment: `code`
        rdd.filter(new Function<Tuple2<Row, Long>, Boolean>(){
            public Boolean call(Tuple2<Row, Long> v1){
                return v1._2 >= start && v1._2 < end;
            });
    `code`