# How to add a new column to a Spark RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD with **MANY** columns (e.g., **hundreds**), how do I add one more column at the end of this RDD?

For example, if my RDD is like below:

```
    123, 523, 534, ..., 893
    536, 98, 1623, ..., 98472
    537, 89, 83640, ..., 9265
    7297, 98364, 9, ..., 735
    ......
    29, 94, 956, ..., 758
```

how can I add a column to it, whose value is the sum of the second and the third columns?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that dataframes are immutable.  You can't change one, but you can make a new one from an old one... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109916/updating-a-dataframe-column-in-spark

Answer (score 9):

You do not have to use `Tuple`* objects at all for adding a new column to an `RDD`.

It can be done by mapping each row, taking its original contents plus the elements you want to append, for example:

```
val rdd = ...
val withAppendedColumnsRdd = rdd.map(row => {
  val originalColumns = row.toSeq.toList
  val secondColValue = originalColumns(1).asInstanceOf[Int]
  val thirdColValue = originalColumns(2).asInstanceOf[Int]
  val newColumnValue = secondColValue + thirdColValue 
  Row.fromSeq(originalColumns :+ newColumnValue)
  // Row.fromSeq(originalColumns ++ List(newColumnValue1, newColumnValue2, ...)) // or add several new columns
})
```

Answer (score 4):

you have RDD of tuple 4, apply map and convert it to tuple5

```
val rddTuple4RDD = ...........
val rddTuple5RDD = rddTuple4RDD.map(r=> Tuple5(rddTuple4._1, rddTuple4._2, rddTuple4._3, rddTuple4._4, rddTuple4._2 + rddTuple4._3))
```

Comment: Thanks sb'. One problem is that in my real data, there are many columns (e.g., hundreds), it is not easy to enumerate the values of all columns. Is there a way to handle many columns?