# How to calculate a column in a Row using two columns of the previous Row in Spark Data Frame?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm trying to calculate a compound interest (kind-of) using `spark` (any flavor:  `pyspark`, `spark`, `spark sql`, etc).

My data has the following shape:

```
+------------+------+------+--------+
| population | rate | year | city   |
+------------+------+------+--------+
| 100        | 0.1  | 1    | one    |
+------------+------+------+--------+
| 100        | 0.11 | 2    | one    |
+------------+------+------+--------+
| 100        | 0.12 | 3    | one    |
+------------+------+------+--------+
| 200        | 0.1  | 1    | two    |
+------------+------+------+--------+
| 1000       | 0.21 | 2    | three  |
+------------+------+------+--------+
| 1000       | 0.22 | 3    | three  |
+------------+------+------+--------+
```

The `population` column is wrong (it came from a `join` between two tables, not shown).

I want to update the `population` column with the result of the `population*(1 + rate)` of the previous row. I know that in `sql` I could use `recursive CTE`s but `hiveql` doesn't support it.

Could you give me some suggestions?

Comment: I think that the natural way of partition the data is withthe `city` column. I tried with window functions, but it failed (or maybe I failed) But I couldn't figure out how to use in the next row a column that doesn't exist yet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109916/updating-a-dataframe-column-in-spark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand your description all you need is some basic algebra and window functions. First lets recreate example data:

```py
import pandas as pd  # Just to make a reproducible example

pdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'city': {0: 'one', 1: 'one', 2: 'one', 3: 'two', 4: 'three', 5: 'three'},
    'population': {0: 100, 1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 200, 4: 1000, 5: 1000},
    'rate': {0: 0.10000000000000001,
     1: 0.11,
     2: 0.12,
     3: 0.10000000000000001,
     4: 0.20999999999999999,
     5: 0.22},
    'year': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3}})

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pdf)

df.show()
## +-----+----------+----+----+
## | city|population|rate|year|
## +-----+----------+----+----+
## |  one|       100| 0.1|   1|
## |  one|       100|0.11|   2|
## |  one|       100|0.12|   3|
## |  two|       200| 0.1|   1|
## |three|      1000|0.21|   2|
## |three|      1000|0.22|   3|
## +-----+----------+----+----+
```

Next we lets define the windows:

```py
import sys
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import exp, log, sum, first, col, coalesce

# Base window
w = Window.partitionBy("city").orderBy("year")

# ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
wr = w.rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, -1)
```

and some columns:

```py
# Take a sum of logarithms of rates over the window
log_sum = sum(log(col("rate") + 1)).over(wr)

# Take sum of logs and exponentiate to go back to original space 
cumulative_rate = exp(log_sum).alias("cumulative_rate")

# Find base population for each group
base_population = first("population").over(w).alias("base_population")

# Prepare final column (base population * cumulative product of rates)
current_population = coalesce(
     # This is null for the first observation in a group
     cumulative_rate * base_population, 
     # so we provide population as an alternative
     col("population")  
).alias("current_population")
```

Finally we can use these as follows

```py
df.select("*", current_population).show()

## +-----+----------+----+----+------------------+
## | city|population|rate|year|current_population|
## +-----+----------+----+----+------------------+
## |three|      1000|0.21|   2|            1000.0|
## |three|      1000|0.22|   3|            1210.0|
## |  two|       200| 0.1|   1|             200.0|
## |  one|       100| 0.1|   1|             100.0|
## |  one|       100|0.11|   2|110.00000000000001|
## |  one|       100|0.12|   3|122.10000000000004|
## +-----+----------+----+----+------------------+
```

Comment: Awesome answer! And It works! Just one question, Could you point to the documentation of the method `coalesce`? Or some explanation?

Comment: It is a standard SQL coalesce - it chooses first not null column. Since `wr` will be empty on the first element in a group, log sum evaluates to `null` and we move to population.    [Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce)