# How to modify/transform the column of a dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an instance of `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` created using

```
dataframe = sqlContext.sql("select * from table").
```

One column is 'arrival_date' and contains a string.

How do I modify this column so as to only take the first 4 characters from it and throw away the rest?

How would I convert the type of this column from string to date?

In graphlab.SFrame, this would be:

```
dataframe['column_name'] = dataframe['column_name'].apply(lambda x: x[:4] )
```

and

```
dataframe['column_name'] = dataframe['column_name'].str_to_datetime()
```

Comment: @Orions I just had not had time to test out the proposed solutions yet. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I wanted to give myself enough time to test each answer and find one that works before accepting one. Thank you for your reminder. I will do this now. And thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated by Orions, you can't modify a column, but you can override it. Also, you shouldn't need to create an user defined function, as there is a built-in function for extracting substrings:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = df.withColumn("arrival_date", df['arrival_date'].substr(0, 4))
```

To convert it to date, you can use `to_date`, as Orions said:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = df.withColumn("arrival_date", to_date(df['arrival_date'].substr(0, 4)))
```

However, if you need to specify the format, you should use `unix_timestamp`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
format = 'yyMM'
col = unix_timestamp(df['arrival_date'].substr(0, 4), format).cast('timestamp')
df = df.withColumn("arrival_date", col)
```

All this can be found in the [pyspark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions).

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and got no error but all the values in the new column became 'null' instead of a meaningful number. Do you think the issue was the format which I chose as "mm/dd/yyyy"? (Dates are in the format of 5/16/2016)

Comment: @Semihcan you need to adapt the format based on what is in the string. How are the values in the original column like?

Comment: May 16th 2016 would be like 5/16/2016, which looks like m/dd/yyyy but December 15 2016 is 12/16/2016 which is like mm/dd/yyyy
So it is tricky for me to know whether to enter mm/dd/yyyy or m/dd/yyyy etc

Comment: @Semihcan. So you need more than just 4 characters. And you can use "M/dd/yyyy" as the format

Comment: I am using the entire string in the column now instead of just 4 characters. (I had originally asked for 4 characters to separate year) Will using M/D/yyyy work also? Since 12/3/2016 is also a possible date?

Comment: @Semihcan, you can try "M/d/yyyy". I can't test it right now, but I think it would work

Comment: Also in your answer you seem to use `df` and `old_df`. I am guessing `df` also refers to the old df?

Comment: @Semihcan, yes df=old_df. Sorry

Comment: I tried
`format = 'm/d/yyyy'
col = unix_timestamp(dataframe['arrival_date'], format).cast('timestamp')
new_df = dataframe.withColumn("arrival_date", col)`
For some reason this yields to 1/5/2016 being converted to 1970-01-17T19:19:12.060+0000

Comment: @Semihcan, have you tried with uppercase "M"?  Lowercase is for minutes

Comment: Yes, I tried both Upper "M" and lower case "m". Same with 'd'. Still getting 1970.

Comment: @Semihcan, are you using spark version 1.6 or higher?

Comment: I am using 1.5.2. (this is what databricks offers me)

Comment: @Semihcan, ok. There is a bug in your version. You must multiply the result of Unix_timestamp() by 1000 before casting

Answer (score 4):

To extract first 4 characters from the `arrival_date` (StringType) column, create a `new_df` by using `UserDefinedFunction` (as you cannot modify the columns: they are immutable):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction, to_date

old_df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table")
udf = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: str(x)[:4], StringType())
new_df = old_df.select(*[udf(column).alias('arrival_date') if column == 'arrival_date' else column for column in old_df.columns])
```

And to covert the `arrival_date` (StringType) column into `DateType` column, use the `to_date` function as show below:

```
new_df = old_df.select(old_df.other_cols_if_any, to_date(old_df.arrival_date).alias('arrival_date'))
```

Sources:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29257220/2873538 
https://databricks.com/blog/2015/09/16/apache-spark-1-5-dataframe-api-highlights.html

Comment: See [Daniel de Paula's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39065383/2738164) for a much more efficient way to accomplish a new substring column.  Declaring and using a UDF for this is extremely inefficient, and you can easily add a column to an existing dataframe without needing to build an entirely new one as well.