# Updating a column in pyspark dependent on the column current value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Lets say given a DataFrame

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|    x|    y|    z|
+-----|-----+-----+
|    3|    5|    9|
|    2|    4|    6|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

I want to multiply all of the values in `z` column by the value in `y` column where `z` column equals 6.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34405348/5368083) post shows the solution I am aiming for, using the code

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn('z',
    F.when(df['z']==6, df['z']*df['y']).
    otherwise(df['z']))
```

The problem is that `df['z']` and `df['y']` are recognized as Column object and casting them won't work...

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: what would you do in scala if you needed the number anyway? lets say I want to duplicate by some list[df['z']] index

Comment: try this one `df = df.withColumn('new_col', F.when(df.z==6, (df.z * df.y)).otherwise(df.z))`

Comment: Doesn't work :/

Comment: does `z` exists in `df` before performing multiplication ?

Comment: Yes it does how could we do that otherwise :)

Comment: `from pyspark.sql.types import LongType` and  `df = df.withColumn('new_col', F.when(df.z==6, (df.z.cast(LongType()) * df.y.cast(LongType()))).otherwise(df.z))`

Comment: No need, it worked!

Comment: Great. I posted an answer. Let me know if any correction/help needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType

df = df.withColumn('new_col', 
            F.when(df.z==6, 
                (df.z.cast(LongType()) * df.y.cast(LongType()))
            ).otherwise(df.z)
     )
```