# Unable to assign new value to a column in pyspark dataframe using column attribute

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe `event1`. It has many columns and one of them is `eventAction` having categorical values like 'conversion', 'check-out', etc.

I wanted to convert this column in a way that 'conversion' becomes 1 and other categories become 0 in `eventAction` column.

This is what I tried:

```
event1.eventAction = event1.select(F.when(F.col('eventAction') == 'conversion', 1).otherwise(0))
event1.show()
```

But I don't see any change in `eventAction` column when `.show()` is executed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a new column to a Spark DataFrame (using PySpark)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681487/how-do-i-add-a-new-column-to-a-spark-dataframe-using-pyspark)

Comment: And this one: [Updating a dataframe column in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109916/updating-a-dataframe-column-in-spark)

Comment: @blackbishop those questions may be related, but frankly, the answers are all over-complicated / even irrelevant to this relatively simple question.

Comment: @blackbishop This question is different in that it used a somewhat intuitive approach to update columns through the column attribute of the dataframe, but somehow failed and thus confused the OP. This usage, though incorrect, has not been asked before, so it's worth being left open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark dataframes are immutable, so you cannot change the column directly using the `.` notation. You need to create a new dataframe that replaces the existing column using `withColumn`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

event1 = event1.withColumn(
    'eventAction', 
    F.when(F.col('eventAction') == 'conversion', 1).otherwise(0)
)
```