# transform rdd into pairRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is a newbie question.

Is it possible to transform an RDD like `(key,1,2,3,4,5,5,666,789,...)` with a dynamic dimension into a pairRDD like `(key, (1,2,3,4,5,5,666,789,...))`?

I feel like it should be super-easy but I cannot get how to.

The point of doing it is that I would like to sum all the values, but not the key.

Any help is appreciated.

I am using Spark 1.2.0

EDIT enlightened by the answer I explain my use case deeplier. I have N (unknown at compile time) different pairRDD (key, value), that have to be joined and whose values must be summed up. Is there a better way than the one I was thinking?

Comment: Are elements of type scala tuple?

Comment: at the moment they are just integers, i am thinking of collecting them in a tuple, yes, unless you have better ideas. I am open to discussion

Comment: I think i dont uderstand. Do you wanna get rdd with one element, contaning a pair of first element of your rdd as key and the rest as a value?

Comment: i want to obtain a pairRDD where the first element is the first element of the starting RDD and the second is a tuple of all the stuff that was in the original RDD except for the first element. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yeah but this is not viable. If you do so you will collect all but one elements of your rdd on one node. And it porbably crush from lack off memeory (if your rdd is large).

Comment: Now I am not understanding. Can't i do this operation partitioning the rdd in length? If i use 3 partitions I'll have N/3 rows to be computed per partition. No? To compute a single operation I just need to read one line, not more.

Comment: You can create scalla tuple (key, rddContaingAllButOne) on driver this is ok. But in case of pairRDD its different. Your piar would be single element off rdd witch would be stored in a single partition.

Comment: It is not easy to get the first element from an RDD. You can have an idea of what involves reading [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828815/how-to-get-elemnt-by-index-in-spark-rdd-java). It will give you a hint about how to proceed.

Comment: @Irene what is the type of the original RDD?

Answer (score 2):

First of all if you just wanna sum all integers but first the simplest way would be:

```scala
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3))
rdd.cache()
val first = rdd.sum()
val result = rdd.count - first
```

On the other hand if you want to have access to the index of elements you can use rdd zipWithIndex method like this:

```scala
  val indexed = rdd.zipWithIndex()
  indexed.cache()
  val result = (indexed.first()._2, indexed.filter(_._1 != 1))
```

But in your case this feels like overkill.

One more thing i would add, this looks like questionable desine to put key as first element of your rdd. Why not just instead use pairs (key, rdd) in your driver program. Its quite hard to reason about order of elements in rdd and i cant not think about natural situation in witch key is computed as first element of rdd (ofc i dont know your usecase so i can only guess).

**EDIT**

If you have one rdd of key value pairs and you want to sum them by key then do just:

```scal
val result = rdd.reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

If you have many rdds of key value pairs before counting you can just sum them up

```scala
  val list = List(pairRDD0, pairRDD1, pairRDD2)
  //another pairRDD arives in runtime
  val newList = anotherPairRDD0::list
  val pairRDD = newList.reduce(_ union _)
  val resultSoFar = pairRDD.reduceByKey(_ + _)
  //another pairRDD arives in runtime
  val result = resultSoFar.union(anotherPairRDD1).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

**EDIT**

I edited example. As you can see you can add additional rdd when every it comes up in runtime. This is because reduceByKey returns rdd of the same type so you can iterate this operation (Ofc you will have to consider performence).

Comment: thank you for your help. According to your explanation I edited the question, do you have any better advice?

Comment: your answer greatly helps but the problem is that i fo not know the number of pairedRDD at compile time, therefore it is impossible to write the val list as you did. Is there any way to do this?