# Is there a way to sample a Spark RDD for exactly a specified number of elements instead of a percentage?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I currently need to randomly sample items in a RDD in Spark for k elements. I noticed that there is the `takeSample` method. The method signature is as follows.

```
takeSample(withReplacement: Boolean, num: Int, seed: Long = Utils.random.nextLong): Array[T]
```

However, this does not return a RDD. There is another sampling method that does return a RDD, `sample`.

```
sample(withReplacement: Boolean, fraction: Double, seed: Long = Utils.random.nextLong): RDD[T]
```

I don't want to use the first method `takeSample` because it does not return a RDD and will pull a significant amount of data back to the driver program (memory issues). I went ahead and used the `sample` method, but I had to compute the `fraction` (percentage) as follows.

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("some/path") //creates the rdd
val N = rdd.count() //total items in the rdd
val fraction = k / N.toDouble
val sampledRdd = rdd.sample(false, fraction, 67L)
```

The problem with this approach/method is that I may not be able to get a RDD with exactly k items. For example, if we assume N = 10, then

- k = 2, fraction = 20%, sampled items = 2
- k = 3, fraction = 30%, sampled items = 3
- and so on

But with N = 11, then

- k = 2, fraction = 18.1818%, sampled items = ?
- k = 3, fraction = 27.2727%, sampled items = ?

In the last example, for fraction = 18.1818%, how many items will be in the resulting RDD?

Also, this is what the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) says about the fraction argument.

```
expected size of the sample as a fraction of this RDD's size 
 - without replacement: probability that each element is chosen; fraction must be [0, 1] 
 - with replacement: expected number of times each element is chosen; fraction must be greater than or equal to 0
```

Since I have chose `without replacement`, it seems that my fraction should be computed as follows. Note that each item has equal probability to be selected (which is what I'm trying to express).

```
val N = rdd.count()
val fraction = 1 / N.toDouble
val sampleRdd = rdd.sample(false, fraction, 67L)
```

So, is it `k / N` or `1 / N`? It seems as if the documentation is pointing in all different directions with sample size and sampling probability.

And lastly, the documentation notes.

> This is NOT guaranteed to provide exactly the fraction of the count of the given RDD.

Which, then brings me back to my original question/concern: if the RDD API doesn't guarantee sampling exactly k items from an RDD, how do we efficiently do so?

As I was writing this post, I discovered there is already [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837530/how-to-get-a-sample-with-an-exact-sample-size-in-spark-rdd) asking nearly the same question. I found the accepted answer unacceptable. Here, I also wanted to clarify the fraction argument.

I wonder if there is a way to do so using Datasets and DataFrames?

Answer (score 2):

This solution is not that beautiful but I hope it would be helpful for thinking.
The trick is using an additional score and get the kth largest score as the threshold.

```
val k = 100
val rdd = sc.parallelize(0 until 1000)
val rddWithScore = rdd.map((_, Math.random))
rddWithScore.cache()
val threshold = rddWithScore.map(_._2)
  .sortBy(t => t)
  .zipWithIndex()
  .filter(_._2 == k)
  .collect()
  .head._1
val rddSample = rddWithScore.filter(_._2 < threshold).map(_._1)
rddSample.count()
```

The output would be

```
k: Int = 100
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[58] at parallelize at <console>:31
rddWithScore: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Double)] = MapPartitionsRDD[59] at map at <console>:32
threshold: Double = 0.1180443408900893
rddSample: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = MapPartitionsRDD[69] at map at <console>:40
res10: Long = 100
```